# How can i put a download Link in Dojo Grid

Tags: dojo

I want to put a download link inside Dojo grid . can any one provide me way to generating link in json

Layout
    var layout = [{
                    field: 'id',
                    name: 'id',
                    width: '100px'
                },
             {
                    field: 'Download',
                    name: 'Download',
                    width: '100px'
                }];

```
Java code for generation Json 

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("Id", "1");
        json.put("ProductName", "Download Link");
        JSONArray  finalArray = new JSONArray();
        finalArray.add(json);

        setResponse(getTopLevelJsonObject(finalArray).serialize(true));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to put a link in a `dgrid` cell, then you need to override the column's `renderCell` function.

e.g.

```
    columns: {
        id: {label:'ID'},
        name: {
            label:'Name',
            renderCell: function(object, value, node, options) {
                var anchor = domConstruct.create("a");
                anchor.href = "http://www.google.com";
                anchor.innerHTML = value;
                return anchor;
            }
        }
    },
```

Here's a [jsfiddle of an anchor/link in a dgrid cell.](http://jsfiddle.net/inanutshellus/h36oh1pr/)

Comment: I'm guessing the question is about `dojox/grid` based on the layout in the question, but it would've been helpful if the question was clearer about that :)